# How to get the profile picture of a page using the Facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to show the profile picture of a Facebook page using the Graph api, but I'm not sure what parameter I need for that.

When I try the following (stripped down example only showing the part where I  loop the images):

```
foreach ( $feedarray->data as $key => $feed_data )
{
    $facebookfeed .= $feed_data->picture;
}
echo $facebookfeed;
```

The image of the associated post is shown, instead of the profile picture of the page where I'm getting the posts from.

So if `picture` is not correct, what is?

Comment: Do you want to show the profile picture of the page the post is on, or of the account that made the post (could be two different profiles)? For the former - you already _have_ the page name or id (because how else would you read its feed) - so why would you try and find that in the feed data in the first place? And for the latter - you’d have to go via the `from` field first, and then get the profile picture of that.

Comment: @CBroe Of the account. I can just paste the link inside an image tag, but I would like it to be dynamic, so that when the user changes his profile picture, it is automatically updated.

Comment: Well the best way to automatically show the current profile picture automatically, is to just use the `https://graph.facebook.com/user-id/picture` address as an image source, that will automatically redirect to the location of the current profile pic on the CDN. So for that, all you would need is to get the user id from the `from` object.

Comment: Alright, easier than I thought, thanks.